# PySimpleGUI textbox border color

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Is there a way to change the color of the textbox border only?
This code results in changing the background color. I just want the border color changed to red.

```
[sg.Input("textbox",size=(20, 1),background_color="red")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no option for boder color in `sg.InputText`, here's example for you and it work under my WIN 10. Tkinter code required for it.

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
    layout = [
        [sg.Input("textbox", size=(20, 1), key='-INPUT-')],
    ]
    window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
    window['-INPUT-'].Widget.configure(highlightcolor='red', highlightthickness=2)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
            break
        print(event, values)

    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this works. What does the finalize parameter do?

Comment: Many of the Window methods require you to either call `Window.read` or `Window.Finalize` (or set `finalize=True` in your Window call) before you call the method. This is because these 2 calls are what actually creates the window using the underlying GUI Framework. Prior to one of those calls, the methods are likely to crash as they will not yet have their underlying widgets created.

Comment: ah got it. Thanks again.